# Server side: Fill form on a webpage

Tags: php, python, arrays, server

Lets say there's a form on a webpage with URL xyz.com . The form has some text input fields, some drop down selections to be made etc. I need to write a server side script to visit this web page and fill and submit the form. Note that the server doesn't have a browser environment.

What should I do to achieve this? Any techniques in PHP (using cURL) or Python or echoing Java script via PHP ? I'd also have the form field IDs with me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a web form on submit goes to a specified URL with some variables attached. You just do, for example, http://www.w3schools.com/html/action_page.php?firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse and that is it.